# Floor Plan rooms coloring according to their name

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ocr

My Goal here is to color each room in the Floor plan according to the word written in each room.
So for example if the word written is bedroom, color it blue and so on.
I have made some adjustments to a code I found earlier here that color each room randomly.
For this code to work, the rooms must be closed to be identified as a separate contour, so I had to close the rooms manually with paint until I make a code to close it (I am open for suggestions for this matter as well but It's not the main problem)

[image]

I used Arabic OCR library:

```
image_path='/content/Y2.jpg'
out_image='out.jpg'
results=arabicocr.arabic_ocr(image_path,out_image)
```

The results variable contains 3 things: ('The coordinates of the contour around the word',"The arabic word", "and how much confidence that the arabic word is accurate")
below is an example of the output:

```
[[[106, 322], [138, 322], [138, 386], [106, 386]], '٣', 0.3450655038380312], [[[742, 412], [832, 412], [832, 456], [742, 456]], 'غرفة', 0.9943901896476746], [[[834, 386], [866, 386], [866, 450], [834, 450]], '؟', 0.9946355239663696], [[[490, 440], [518, 440], [518, 478], [490, 478]], '8', 0.9978250183434092]
```

The out_image from the arabic_ocr library looks like this (but that's not what I want)

[image]

What I want is an image that looks more like this:

[image]

but with each room colored according to the written text

This is the main code:

```
gap_in_wall_threshold=1000
ret, labels = cv2.connectedComponents(thresh)
image = cv2.cvtColor(thresh,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
unique = np.unique(labels)
rooms = []


for i in range(len(results)):

  if is_float(results[i][1]) or contains_arabic_numeral(results[i][1]) or results[i][1]=='' or results[i][1]=='؟':
    continue

  else:
    x,y = results[i][0][0]
    for label in unique:
        component = labels == label
        #print(component,"= component")
        if image[component].sum() == 0 or np.count_nonzero(component) < gap_in_wall_threshold:
            color = 0
            image[component]=color
        else:

            if component[x, y] :
                color = Room_Color(results[i][1])
                #color = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=3)
                rooms.append(component)
                image[component] = color

            else:
                color = [0,0,0]
                image[component] = color


cv2_imshow(image)
```

The code gives me a black image and I have failed to identify the problem, can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277790/42659